# How to unit test a generator/serialization method?

Tags: unit-testing

I want to write unit tests for a serialization method. By serialization method I mean a methd that outputs a set of data into a special format.

For example, a method that outputs data in XML format. (I write in C++ but it is the same in every language.)

```
class Generator
{
public:
    std::string serialize();
};

// unit test (pseudo-code)
Generator gen;
// set some data in gen
std::string actual = gen.serialize();
std::string expected = "<xml>...</xml>";
ASSERT_EQUAL(expected, actual);
```

The problem with this is that the unit test is highly dependent on non-important things, like the formatting of the XML (line breaks) or the order of XML-attributes.

While with XML the previous method will work, it will not work with generators that output binary data.

So, what is a robust way to test serialization methods?

---

The ideas I have are the following, but all have serious drawbacks.

- using external libraries to parse the data (for proprietary formats, there may not exist).
- always write pairs of serialization/deserialization and test them in combination (bugs in both methods might remain undiscovered).
- store the serialized data in external files and compare against them in the test (the unit test is difficult to read and maintain).

Comment: Personally I prefer the second option of doing the tests in pairs. The chances of having complimentary bugs in the serialiser and deserialiser are small I'd say. If you have a bug in the serialiser you'll probably find it when you deserialse and validate the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are asking about unit-testing, I assume that the intended behaviour of the serializer in all its details is known by you.  That is, you know where you want line breaks and indentation etc. to be inserted.

The problem now is, that in every single test case only a subset of these details would be relevant.  In other words, in some tests you want to test the proper indentation, and in some tests you just want to be sure that a number is inserted in the right way.

In addition to the options you have provided I recommend another approach: Use regular expression matching instead of string comparison.  With the help of regular expressions you can reduce the serialized string to the essential parts which are of interest in the respective test.  To check, for example, if the result string contains a certain number, say, 42, you could match it against `^[^0-9]*42[^0-9]*$`.  Then, the enclosing XML would be ignored in this particular test.  This test would then be robust against a large number of changes in the serialization.

With this approach you avoid the dependency on external parsing libraries (well, you are depending on the regular expression library, but that is in many languages today even part of the standard library), you can also test for aspects which the serialize-deserialize can not test (indentation), your tests run fast and are not OS specific (no dependency on the file system).

Comment: Good point. With my 3 points and this one, I am pretty happy with the solution. Four years later it is not urgent any more, but still valuable.

Answer (score 1):

*This is more like a long comment with my first thoughts on the topic.*

I think you have to look at two different scenarios. Your data <-> serialized data relation could be either 1:1 or 1:n.

XML would be a 1:n relation, where you XML code would have quite a little bit of freedom, but would still be unserialized to the same data again. In this case it seems to me, that developing and testing serialization/deserialization in combination is the way to go. If there are external libraries available as well, use them of course. If there are no external libraries available, then - as long as serialization / deserialization - yield the same result, you will probably not have "bugs", but "features"...
Testing the deserialization with stored external datafiles does also make sense, but this does not apply to the serialization, imho.

Looking at a 1:1 relation, like maybe putting the data into a certain binary format, you should go for the stored data in external files. Always use external libraries, if they exist, as well, of course.

I would suggest to do all three of those approaches together - where applicable, of course. You should not rely on a single one of them.